# Get SKU of product in cart Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the SKU of all the products in my cart. 
In the past i tried something similar with the product names. I did it like this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$product_names=array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; 
    $product_names[]=$_product->post_title; 
}
```

Is there a way like this but instead of the title get the SKU of a product?

EDIT:

I tried Thoby's way like this :

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$product_names=array();
$productsku=array();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; 
    $product_names[]=$_product->post_title;
    $productsku[]=  $_woo_product->get_sku();
}
```

But i get an error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Post::get_sku()

Comment: The product object should have an sku property. Have you tried returning the $_product object and seeing what properties it has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$product_names = array();

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 

    // Retrieve WC_Product object from the product-id:
    $_woo_product = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );

    // Get SKU from the WC_Product object:
    $product_names[] = $_woo_product->get_sku(); 
}
```

The official WooCommerce API docs: [wc_get_product()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)

Comment: You didn't seem to have copied the content of my code. I use the function wc_get_product, which would return a WC_Product object instead of a WC_Post.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this might help you-

```
$_product->get_sku();
```

It works with product loops and you can use it inside your cart/checkout/etc..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have access to `$cart`

```
$cart_items = $cart->get_cart_contents();
$skus = array(); 

foreach($cart_items as $cart_item) {     

 // Get WC_Product by Variation ID, if not avaiable use Product ID
 $product = wc_get_product($cart_item["variation_id"] ? $cart_item["variation_id"] : 
 $cart_item["product_id"]);

 // Add new SKU to array
 array_push($skus, $product->get_sku());     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the SKU of a product when you have access to the cart items:

```
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
  
foreach( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    $product->get_sku();

}
```